# How to add posts in wordpress pages?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show some posts in the homepage of my wordpress site..How will I do it??or is there any plugin that can help me do it?or is there shortcodes that could pull out and display those post in my homepage?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it the easy way, you can use a plugin like [Display Posts Shortcode](http://wordpress.org/plugins/display-posts-shortcode/).

Or, if you want to do it manually, you can use [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).

Here's an example you could use:

```
<?php
if (is_page()) {
  $cat=get_cat_ID($post->post_title); //use page title to get a category ID
  $posts = get_posts ("cat=$cat&showposts=5");
  if ($posts) {
    foreach ($posts as $post):
      setup_postdata($post); ?>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php endforeach;
  }
}
?>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

The implemetation varies greatly by theme.
Check if your wordpress theme has a file called index.php. 
If you have this file for your current theme, this is the file responsible for displaying your home page. And this is where you will have to put the code snippets to display posts.

Presuming that you know a bit of html and PHP you will have to decide the suitable place within index.php to add the code suggested above by Amal Murali.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show a specific category post on Homepage you can use category slug or category name. Like the below to show and use the [`wp_pagenavi()`](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi) plugin to show pagination and present it.

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var( 'paged' )) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category_name' => 'CATEGORY NAME ',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged,
);
$arr_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) :

    while ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) :
        $arr_posts->the_post();
        ?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <?php
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
                the_post_thumbnail();
            endif;
            ?>
            <header class="entry-header">
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            </header>
            <div class="entry-content">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
            </div>
        </article>
        <?php
    endwhile;
    wp_pagenavi(
        array(
            'query' => $arr_posts,
        )
    );
endif;
?>
```